# Git in Eclipse: How can I overwrite the changes on the repo?

Tags: eclipse, git, repository, conflict

I am very new with git and repositorys and I have a problem. Me and my collegue were working on the same file.

1. He commited and pushed his changes.
2. I commited my changes
3. I pulled

Now I have conflicts and I want to solve them. How can I overwrite the conflicts so that my changes are on the file? I am working with Eclipse.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fix merge conflicts in Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161813/fix-merge-conflicts-in-git)

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to resolve conflicts. But tools are available to make the process a little easier. Anyhow you will have to decide and manually make the changes so that both of your changes are available in the latest file.

Try: `git mergetool`

If you both edited separate parts of the file then the tool will automatically merge whereas if you both have edited the same part then some manual interaction is needed.

Comment: I can't resolve them manually. I am not able to change the file on the repo.

Answer (score 0):

If you want **Your changes** you can use:

```
git fetch -p
git merge --ours
```

This will merge the remote with your local branches and in case of any conflict - use **your** version of code.